# jquery validate textboxes and then submit the code in sql server

Tags: jquery, validation, asp-classic

In my web application, I want to insert the value of a textbox into my database - but first, validate that all of the fields are filled.

Currently, my code relies on a large series of `if {}` conditions, and I'd like to make it more elegant. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function () {
    $('#BtnInquiryPageSave').click(function () {
        if ($("#TbFirstName").val().toLowerCase() == "") {
            $('#TbFirstName').addClass('RequiredField');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }

        if ($("#TbRequestedCharterDate").val().toLowerCase() == "") {
            $('#TbRequestedCharterDate').addClass('RequiredField');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        if ($("#TbEndDate").val().toLowerCase() == "") {
            $('#TbEndDate').addClass('RequiredField');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        if ($("#ddlPersons").val().toLowerCase() == "-1") {
            $('#ddlPersons').addClass('RequiredFieldDdl');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        if ($("#ddlCabin").val().toLowerCase() == "-1") {
            $('#ddlCabin').addClass('RequiredFieldDdl');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        if ($("#ddlBoatSize").val().toLowerCase() == "-1") {
            $('#ddlBoatSize').addClass('RequiredFieldDdl');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_ContentPlaceHolder4_ddlBoatType").val().toLowerCase() == "-1") {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder2_ContentPlaceHolder4_ddlBoatType')
                .addClass('RequiredFieldDdl');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_ContentPlaceHolder4_ddlSource").val().toLowerCase() == "-1") {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder2_ContentPlaceHolder4_ddlSource')
                .addClass('RequiredFieldDdl');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        if ($("#TbOther").val().toLowerCase() == "") {
            $('#TbOther').addClass('RequiredField');
            $('#ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });
});
```

I'd really like a simpler way to test all of these conditions. Ideally, a single `if`/`else` or something similarly easy. I just need to be able to click on `submit` and have it validate... if it fails - show a failure message, and if it succeeds - send the data to the database.

What might a better approach be?

Comment: Why are you using same ids for multiple elements?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use more stable jQuery validation plugin to achieve what you are trying to do?
For example:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: actually i dont want to use any plugin .it will make my app heavy i have tried telerik rad controls in my some preveous project but not now

Comment: and there is another reason i have the page with more than 50 text field so no space to show message ,and resolution is also fix its 1024*760px

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Jquery Validator Plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

This is simple, init with $('#formToValidate').validate();

In the fields on form, add classes like:

```
<form action="" id="formToValidate">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" />
</form>
```

More in: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: actually i dont want to use any plugin .it will make my app heavy i have tried telerik rad controls in my some preveous project but not now

Comment: @user1830210, and getting rid of your long list of `if` statements will make your app a lot **less** heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : http://jsfiddle.net/B8yQs/

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {

   $(':text').each(function () {
       if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).css({
            'border': 'solid 1px red',
             'color': 'red'
        }).val('required.');
       e.preventDefault(); // stops the form from submit
      }
    $(this).focus(function () {
        $(this).css({
            'border': 'solid 1px black',
             'color': 'grey'
           }).val('');
        });
      });
});
```

and you can also try this with your situation but little amends :

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {

   $(':text').each(function () {
       if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('RequiredField');
        $(this).next('.ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'visible');
        //------------^^^^^^^^^^^------------------------use class instead of ids
       e.preventDefault(); // stops the form from submit
      }
    $(this).focus(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('RequiredField');
        $(this).next('.ErrorLable').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
      });
});
```